# How can I get the name of a clicked cell in my listview to load into a new activity?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

[image]

How can I get the name of a specific cell in my listview to load into a new activity ? At present, when I click any of the arrows it loads the last person in my contacts (Yvonne) in the next activity that loads when the arrow is clicked. I want the name in the corresponding cell to load in the next activity. How can I do this?

For example, in the image above, I want Alexi to load into the next Activity. But instead I keep getting Yvonne.

At present my code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    // ArrayList called selectContacts that will contain SelectContact info
    ArrayList<SelectContact> selectContacts;

    ListView listView;

    SearchView search;
    SelectContactAdapter adapter;
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String lookupkey;
    CharSequence nameofcontact;

    //    *****18-04-2016***
    Cursor cursor;
//    ListView mainListView;
//    ArrayList hashMapsArrayList;

    public String cleartext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //selectContacts is an empty array list that will hold our SelectContct info
        selectContacts = new ArrayList<SelectContact>();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);


        //*** setOnQueryTextListener ***
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    // Load data on background
    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

//            Perhaps running this thread on the UI thread has solved the issue of the app
//            crashing? ListView had not been updating properly, I think.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

//          we want to delete the old selectContacts from the listview when the Activity loads
//          because it may need to be updated and we want the user to see the updated listview,
//          like if the user adds new names and numbers to their phone contacts.
                    selectContacts.clear();

//          we have this here to avoid cursor errors
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                    }
                    try {

//                get a handle on the Content Resolver, so we can query the provider,
                        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
//                the table to query
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
//               Null. This means that we are not making any conditional query into the contacts table.
//               Hence, all data is returned into the cursor.
//                                Projection - the columns you want to query
                                        null,
//                                Selection - with this you are extracting records with assigned (by you) conditions and rules
                                        null,
//                                SelectionArgs - This replaces any question marks (?) in the selection string
//                               if you have something like String[] args = { "first string", "second@string.com" };
                                        null,
//                                display in ascending order
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

//                get the column number of the Contact_ID column, make it an integer.
//                I think having it stored as a number makes for faster operations later on.
                        int Idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);
//                get the column number of the DISPLAY_NAME column
                        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
//                 get the column number of the NUMBER column
                        int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

//                ****
                        int contactlookupkey = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY);
//                ****



                        cursor.moveToFirst();

//              We make a new Hashset to hold all our contact_ids, including duplicates, if they come up
                        Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
                        do {
                            System.out.println("=====>in while");
//                  get a handle on the contactid, which is a string. Loop through all the contact_ids
                            String contactid = cursor.getString(Idx);
//                  if our Hashset doesn't already contain the contactid string,
//                    then add it to the hashset
                            if (!ids.contains(contactid)) {
                                ids.add(contactid);

                                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                        get a handle on the display name, which is a string
                                name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
//                        get a handle on the phone number, which is a string
                                phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
//                        String image = cursor.getString(photoIdIdx);

                                lookupkey = cursor.getString(contactlookupkey);

                                System.out.println("Id--->" + contactid + " Name--->" + name);
                                System.out.println("Id--->" + contactid + " Number--->" + phoneNumber);
                                System.out.println("Id--->" + contactid + " lookupkey--->" + lookupkey);


                                SelectContact selectContact = new SelectContact();

                                selectContact.setName(name);
                                selectContact.setPhone(phoneNumber);

                                selectContacts.add(selectContact);
                            }


                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {

                    }
                }});

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

//into each inflate_listview, put a name and phone number, which are the details making
//            our SelectContact, above. And SelectContacts is all these inflate_listviews together
//            This is the first property of our SelectContactAdapter, a list
//            The next part, MainActivity.this, is our context, which is where we want the list to appear
            adapter = new SelectContactAdapter(selectContacts, MainActivity.this);

//            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Select item on listclick
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



                    listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
//                    we need to notify the listview that changes may have been made on
//                    the background thread, doInBackground, like adding or deleting contacts,
//                    and these changes need to be reflected visibly in the listview. It works
//                    in conjunction with selectContacts.clear()

//                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }



            });
        }}

    //the is the arrow image, it opens the activity for show and edit
    public void DisplayorEditContact(View v) {
        System.out.println("works so far");
        System.out.println(name);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditorNewContact.class).putExtra("thecontactname",name);

        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
//I want to clear the searchview text when my app resumes or closes, but I keep getting an error, my app shuts down
//    cleartext =  findViewById(R.id.searchView).toString();
//    cleartext.isEmpty();
//        search.setQuery("", false);
        super.onResume();
//    load the contacts again, refresh them, when the user resumes the activity
        LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
        loadContact.execute();
//    cursor.close();
    }


}
```

The salient part of the code I believe is :

```
//the is the arrow image, it opens the activity for show and edit
public void DisplayorEditContact(View v) {
    System.out.println("works so far");
    System.out.println(name);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditorNewContact.class).putExtra("thecontactname",name);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the child activity, into which I want Alexi to load (at present I keep getting Yvonne) looks like this :

```
public class EditorNewContact extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_contact);

        String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("thecontactname");
        System.out.println("the name is" + s);

        EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edittext.setText(s);
```

I was asked to share my `SelectContactAdapter`, so here it is :

```
public class SelectContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //define a list made out of SelectContacts and call it _data
    public List<SelectContact> _data;
    //define an array list made out of SelectContacts and call it arraylist
    private ArrayList<SelectContact> arraylist;
    Context _c;

    //define a ViewHolder to hold our name and number info, instead of constantly querying
    // findviewbyid. Makes the ListView run smoother
    ViewHolder v;

//    RoundImage roundedImage;

    public SelectContactAdapter(List<SelectContact> selectContacts, Context context) {
        _data = selectContacts;
        _c = context;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectContact>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return _data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        //we're naming our convertView as view
        View view = convertView;
        //if there is nothing there (if it's null) inflate the layout for each row
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.inflate_listview, null);
//            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");

            //or else use the view (what we can see in each row) that is already there
        } else {
            view = convertView;
//            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
        }

        v = new ViewHolder();

//      So, for example, title is cast to the name id, in activity main,
//        phone is cast to the id called no etc
        v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
//        v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
        v.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.arrowright);

//        for each new cell with title, name, number etc...
//
        final SelectContact data = (SelectContact) _data.get(i);
        v.title.setText(data.getName());
//        v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
        v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

        view.setTag(data);
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
//        _data is our list of contacts
        _data.clear();
//        If there is nothing in the searchview, if the charText length is 0,
//        then show all the contacts
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            _data.addAll(arraylist);
//            or else....
        } else {
            for (SelectContact wp : arraylist) {
//                If a contact's name matches the input thus far, which is charText,
//                then include it in the listview.
                if ((wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) || (wp.getPhone().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)))
                     {

                        _data.add(wp);
                    }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
//        In each cell in the listview show the items you want to have
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, phone;
//        CheckBox check;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your SelectContactAdapter.java

Comment: @Harsh4789 I've added my SelectContactsAdapter, thanks.

Comment: You always want to get your data from the adapter. That should give you the accurate location of the clicked item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add following line to your `SelectContactsAdapter.java`

```
final SelectContact data = (SelectContact) _data.get(i);
v.title.setText(data.getName());
v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

// Please add this line to your existing code right after above lines
v.imageView.setTag(data.getName());
```

Modify your method as below

```
public void DisplayorEditContact(View v) {
        System.out.println("works so far");
        System.out.println(v.getTag().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditorNewContact.class).putExtra("thecontactname",v.getTag().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to predict how your code works without seeing the `SelectContactAdapter` source code. But I can suggest a probably easiest solution, which is using a [tag](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))

all you need to do is to set a tag to your arrow image somewhere in your adapter's `getView` method like this:

```
youArrowImage.setTag("here_is_a_name_of_a_row");
```

and then in your `DisplayorEditContact(View v)` you can access it like this:

```
String itemName = (String)v.getTag();
```

here I suppose that `v` is a reference to clicked arrow image

Comment: cheers, looking into ur answer now, in the meantime I've added my SelectContactAdapter to question, if you think that can help.

Comment: Cheers R., I went with Harsh above as it was laid out exact what needed to be done. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could also just monitor the click in your ListView `setOnItemClickListener`.

```
// Click listener to bring to profile
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent viewProfileIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
        viewProfileIntent.putExtra("name", selectContacts.get(position));
        Log.i("User Tapped", selectContacts.get(position));
        startActivity(viewProfileIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts Akash, I went with Harsh's...I was having problems with your get(position) in the above code. +1

Comment: No problem, glad I contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Your this method will like this:

```
public void DisplayorEditContact(View v) {

TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_NAME);
    System.out.println(tvName.getText().toString());
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onItemClickListener on your list view.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        SelectContact contact = (SelectContact)parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 

Intent secondActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorNewContact.class);
        secondActivity.putExtra("Key", contact);
        startActivity(secondActivity);
    }
});
```

Also, in your EditorNewContact activity, you will need to resolve this intent in the onCreate method, like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
SelectContact contact = (SelectContact) intent.get("Key");
```

Also, your SelectContact class can be Serializeable, If that is the can, the the intent will look like.

```
Intent secondActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorNewContact.class);
            secondActivity.putSerializeableExtra("Key", contact);
            startActivity(secondActivity);
```

And, to resolve this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    SelectContact contact = (SelectContact) intent.getSerializableExtra("Key");
```

i hope this helps.